# How to define a regex that matches whole words treating "." like a normal letter

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to read a several numbers from a string in Matlab. The aim is to do what `str2num` does, but without using `eval` (and much less advanced).

I already have a regex for matching a valid double number:

```
'([-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.|[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.|[0-9]+))?)'
```

Which works fine for valid substrings such as "1.15e2.4". My problem is that I want to avoid matching invalid substrings such as "1.15.e2.4" (which splits to "1.15" and "2.4").

When I match only whole words (using `\<` and `\>`), the invalid string is split to "1.15" and "4"), because the decimal point is considered a word binary.

For now I am using look-around expressions:

```
'((?<=^|[ :,])[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.|[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.|[0-9]+))?(?=$|[ :,]))'
```

but I wonder if there is an easier and more general way.

Is it possible to redefine which characters are considered word boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redefine what a word boundary means. But you can achieve the same effect by using *negative* lookarounds:

```
(?<!\.)\<   your first regex here   \>(?!\.)
```

Not dramatically simpler than your second regex, but more robust since it does exactly what it says: disallows `.` as a word boundary.